# php echo folder name using glob

Tags: php, arrays, echo, shuffle, glob

The **code used** below will take 10 random files from any of the 3 folders listed in GLOB_BRACE.

**eg:**

```
$files = (glob('../{folder1,folder2,folder3}/*.php', GLOB_BRACE));
```

i would like to echo the folder name in the url seen below $thelist

```
$thelist .= '<p><a href="../'.$folder 1 or 2 or 3.'/'.$file.'">'.$title.'</a></p>';
```

So when it's displayed on my page it reads.

```
<p><a href="../folder1/page-name.php">what ever</a></p>
<p><a href="../folder3/page-name.php">what ever</a></p>
<p><a href="../folder1/page-name.php">what ever</a></p>
<p><a href="../folder2/page-name.php">what ever</a></p>
<p><a href="../folder1/page-name.php">what ever</a></p>
<p><a href="../folder3/page-name.php">what ever</a></p>
<p><a href="../folder2/page-name.php">what ever</a></p>
<p><a href="../folder3/page-name.php">what ever</a></p>
<p><a href="../folder1/page-name.php">what ever</a></p>
<p><a href="../folder2/page-name.php">what ever</a></p>
```

**Code used:**

```
<?php 
$files = (glob('../{folder1,folder2,folder3}/*.php', GLOB_BRACE)); /* change php to the file you require either html php jpg png. */
shuffle($files);
$selection = array_slice($files, 0, 11);

foreach ($selection as $file) {
    $file = basename($file);
    if ($file == 'index.php') continue;

    $title = str_replace('-', ' ', pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME));
        $randomlist .= '<p><a href="../'.$folder 1 or 2 or 3.'/'.$file.'">'.$title.'</a></p>';
    }
?>
<?=$randomlist?>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you having trouble getting the folder name?  `dirname($file)`

Comment: yes i dont know how to get the folder name

Comment: That should be what `dirname($file)` gets you.

Comment: i have tried to add $path = dirname($file); and then add $path to the $randomlist .= '<p><a href="../'.$path.'/'.$file.'">'.$title.'</a></p>'; I'm still learning php you see so i dont know.

Comment: try what I posted below. It isn't actually necessary to do either basename() or dirname().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `glob()` will return the directory and filename. Therefore if you don't reassign `$file` to `basename($file)`, the entire string will remain intact for output. You can still check `basename()` in the `if()` condition to `continue`.

```
foreach ($selection as $file) { 
  // Call basename() in the if condition, but don't reassign the variable $file
  if (basename($file) == 'index.php') continue;

  $title = str_replace('-', ' ', pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME));
  // Using the full `$file` in the HTML output. No need for basename() or dirname().
  // Using htmlentities to encode the file path for an HTML attribute
  $randomlist .= '<p><a href="' . htmlentities($file, ENT_QUOTES) . '">'.$title.'</a></p>';
}
```